# Could not display "network:///" error when browsing LAN

Tags: 10.04, networking, nautilus

Every time I reboot and try to browse the local network I get this error, but if I press OK and try again it works just fine. It only happens once per reboot.
[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with what's producing this message -- your tags seem to suggest this is from nautilus?   And how exactly are you trying to browse the network?

Answer (score 1):

go to places click on computer then enter network:/// in location bar as

network:///

else use 
 sudo apt-get install samba